# Why is $y^2 - x$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Why is $y^2 - x$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$?

Really not sure what technique to use here since the polynomial is multivariate.

Comment: What degree could a factor of that polynomial have?

Comment: @Hurkyl Typo. Fixed, thank you!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Factor would have to have deg <= 1 in x and <= 2 in y?

Comment: Eisenstein works nicely here, though there are simpler arguments too.

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{Q}[x,y] \cong (\mathbb{Q}[x])[y]$ is a UFD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DirectSuperHint:

If $y^2 - x$ is reducible, then there exists polynomials $p,q \in \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ s.t $y^2 - x = pq$, now the degree of this polynomials must be one, i.e, $p = a+bx+cy,q=d + ex + fy$ with $a,b,c,d,e,f \in\mathbb{Q}$. Do the product and equals the coeficients with $y^2-x$ (a system of equations), now you will obtain a contradiction. (Possibly $a=b=c=d=e=f=0$).

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the simplest approach is

- If an element is prime, it is irreducible
- An element is prime if and only if the ideal it generates is prime
- An ideal is prime if and only if the corresponding quotient ring is a domain

and compute the quotient ring

$$ \mathbb{Q}[x,y] / (y^2 - x) $$

(It may help to note that $y^2 - x$ is a monic, linear, univariate polynomial over the coefficient ring $\mathbb{Q}[y]$. This note can help with other approaches too)